# HP E3631A power supply delivers ~32mA on all outputs when the output is OFF but only microamps when the output is ON

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting

I bought a used HP E3631A DC power supply, Triple output: 0- +25V, 0-1A; 0- -25V, 0-1A; 0- 6V, 0-5A 80W

With the outputs off, when I connect a DVM (HP 33401A 6.5 Digit meter) to the output on any of the supply outputs, I measure approximately 32mA on all outputs, polarity of the current depends upon whether I am measuring positive or negative voltages.

When I turn the output of the power supply on with the output set to 0 volts, 0A, the current measured by the meter goes to microamps. When I turn the current on the power supply up to 1A on any of the outputs, the measured current is very close to 1A

I went through the calibration procedure outlined in the User's guide but nothing changed.

It's odd that all three outputs "leak" the same amount of current.

Am I doing something wrong other than buying used equipment?

Comment: I tried similar setup with working HP E3631A and got 22mA on handheld multimeter so I guess this is normal.

Comment: @Rokta Thank you for the response, that is interesting. None of my other HP power supplies leak current.

Comment: You din't mention all details: like OC output voltage, 32mA OK but what polarity - does it sink or source out?

Comment: @Marko Buršič  The supply sinks current in all cases approximately 32mA

Comment: @Marko Buršič I just checked, this power supply doesn't have the over current/over voltage output protection that other HP power supplies have. The polarity of the current sink follows the polarity of the output used. The +25 and +6V supplies sink -32mA of current while the -25V supply sinks +32mA of current

Comment: Your question lacks details on the hardware Rev and references to the schematics in the service manual.  So what would you like to know specifically?  There is no wrong or right. Just better ways to understand, debug, test and repair.  I visited HP's PSU factory in Rockaway NJ for a training session in their excellent facility in '77.  It was the grandfather version of this one with the same familiar HP-IB interface for remote control.  Excellent Linear supplies.

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 I'm trying to determine if I should return this power supply. I was hoping that somebody would say, "you did the calibration wrong" or something like that. With the comments received so far, I believe that something is wrong with the supply. I could dive in and fix it but I have other fires to put out. They are great supplies and I've never had one that I couldn't fix. Nobody wants to fix something that was advertised as "working" Or at least I don't

Comment: It appears to work and passes self test.   What is the OFF voltage?

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 
With the output off, the output voltage is 

-0.279V for the +6V supply, 

-0.336V for the +25V supply 

0.32V for the -25V supply 

https://imgur.com/a/YJuKqJ2

Comment: could it be Y cap leakage? with Schottky diode reverse limiting? don't use  PE in current measurement.   just a swag.. https://gerrysweeney.com/wp-content/plugins/download-attachments/includes/download.php?id=1905

Comment: Do you have a handheld DMM? The strange fact is that this PSU doesn't have an additional negative rail, it only has a 5 kohm bleeding resistor in parallel. IMO, the only way is that this negative voltage comes from external source, then when you enable the output the PSU compensates for that.

Comment: Does this measure the same using a handheld multimeter? Or is it only with mains-powered ones?

Comment: The readings are the same with a handheld DMM.

Amazingly enough, the HP manual status that there can be 50mA of output when the power supply is in the off state

"When the power supply is in the “Off” state, the OFF annunciator turns on and the three outputs are disabled. The OFF annunciator turns off when the power supply returns to the “On” state. When the outputs are disabled, the voltage value is 0 volts and the current value is 0.05 amps."



But this does not explain the non-zero voltage reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9E2EQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since your DMM terminal is connected to the earth, the most plausible explanation is that due to the parasitic capacitance between primary and secondary of the PSU a ground loop is formed. As you can see the polarity of the mounted D2 and D1, they conduct only negative half, so that's why you get a negative voltage and current on positive PSU terminals, and vice-versa and the negative terminals.